# HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError creates empty hprof file

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Sometimes, quite seldom, I encounter strange behavior - hprof file that is generated when OutOfMemoryError is thrown has zero length.

I can think only about disk problem, but this is not the case.

Java is started by: 
/opt/jre-1.6.0_25_FIPS/bin/java -Xms192m -Xmx960m -XX:MaxPermSize=360m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -server -XX:-ReduceInitialCardMarks -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n **-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError** -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jakarta-tomcat-6.0.29/endorsed -classpath ... org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start